# "there were expected" vs "there were expected to be"

Tags: grammaticality

> There aren't half as many guests as **there were expected**.
>
> There aren't half as many guests as **there were expected to be**.

What's the difference if I add in the end of that sentence "to be"? Is it necessary here? Could you explain it?

Comment: I think the sentence would be better off without both **there** (the second one, of course) and **to be.**

Comment: Yes, the comparative clause can be reduced to just "expected", as in "There aren't half as many guests as expected".

Comment: There is also (3) There aren't half as many guests as expected. -- (4) There aren't half as many guests as there were expected to be at the party. You would used these and your examples depending on how much context has already been given and where, or if, you wished to give emphasis.